# Had better NOT Have better

Tags: tense, usage

Why do we use **had** not **have** in had better while the meaning is present or future, not past?

Comment: Could you clarify by providing an example sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is a disguised conditional construction.

*You had better **do** ...* means *It would be better if you **did** ...*

Note that the main verb (that I've represented by *do*) is in the past form used for counterfactuals in the the expanded form. In the shorter form, *had* is in this same counterfactual form.

Compare *Had you been ...* as a literary form of *If you had been ...*

Comment: Thanks! +1. That's an interesting explanation. I had never looked at it this way.